# php: why &nbsp; is not stripped

Tags: php, html

Why `&nbsp;` is not stripped in `strip_tags()`? Other than `str_replace()` any other possibilities?

Comment: `&…;` is not a tag but a reference; only `<…>` is a tag.

Comment: looked around also and seems like str_replace is your best bet.. Weird how none of the answers below actually do what you're asking which is how to strip (a.k.a remove that character). html_entity_decode will replace it with an empty space, not strip it..

Answer (score 21):

Well, it's not a tag :)

Also, yeah, `html_entity_decode` is the way to go.

Comment: In addition, you may try this `html_entity_decode(strip_tags($mystring))`

Answer (score 7):

Unlike HTML tags, entities (such as `&lt;` or `&nbsp;`) represent actual characters.
If you strip all entities from a piece of HTML, you'll ned up stripping all `<` characters, as well as any other characters that were included as entities.

You need to *decode* the entities into the characters that they represent, using the [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

strip_tags() will not remove html entities

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but would [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) work for you? It will turn & nbsp ; into a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 1):

It's not stripped because, according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) it only strips the tags. `&nbsp;` isn't a tag, it's an entity character code. You could use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)